# Access a web server with 3G connection in Saudi Arabia

Tags: windows-8, 3g

I have a web server application installed on a computer connected with 3G connection Mobily in Saudi Arabia. The connection is a prepaid M2M Sim card.
I use a dyndns Host on tis connection to update IP adresse and the connection to internet is established and Dyndns updated. But impossible to reach it from outside. Impossible to ping this host or IP address.
The provider is not giving any axplanation. It seems they block the incoming connections. I tested on STC but same prblem.
Do anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Friendly

Answer (score 0):

Check with the provider whether that the web server is accessed with any specific port other that default ports like 443 or 80. If they are using any ports then add it in firewall exception. Try accessing the web application by disabling the firewall once to check the case.

Also if you are accessing the web application with it IP address check whether it is routed in internal router correctly.